# textbox value split equal in other textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The value for 2nd 3rd and 4th box is fixed as 100 50 50 if the user enters 300 the value should split it into 100 50 50 and remaining 100 should be in balance box...

suppose if the user enters 100 it should fill the first box other box should be zero..

suppose if the user enters 50 it should fill the second box other box should be zero.. like tat i had tried the following code but it has error...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
window.update = function() {
var one = document.getElementById('one'),
  two = document.getElementById('two');    
  three = document.getElementById('three');    
  four = document.getElementById('four');   
  five = document.getElementById('five'); 



two.value = parseInt(one.value) - 100;

//if(two.value < 100)
// {
three.value = parseInt(two.value) - 50;
//}

//if(two.value > 100)
//{
 // three.value = parseInt(two.value) - 0;
four.value = parseInt(three.value) - 50;
//}
five.value = parseInt(three.value) - 50;
}



function checknumber(txtid) {
    var mynumbervalue = parseFloat((txtid).value); 
    if (mynumbervalue > 100) {
                txtid.value = "0";
                alert("Please try again. Values must be between 0-100...");
            }
    if (theid.value < 0) {
                txtid.value = "0";
                alert("Please try again. Values must be between 0-100 ...");
            }
        }     
 </script>
</head>
<body><br><p align="center">
Enter the amount to be paid<input id="one" type="text" onChange="update();" /><br>  
book fees<input id="two" type="text" name="txt"  onchange="checknumber(this)"/> 100<br>
uniform fees<input id="three" type="text" /> 50<br>
Bus fees<input id="four" type="text" /> 50<br>
balance fees<input id="five" type="text" /> <br>

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the user enters something like 87? What is the actual problem you are working on?

Comment: gud qus... if the user enters 87 it shoud take 50 and remaining bal 37 should be in balance box...

Comment: Is this what do you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/7zyQs/6/

Comment: yes this was im trying  thanks frnd..

Comment: code works fine i had tried with onkeypress event it updates the give value but if i press 1 its doents shows in balance box if i press another number for ex same another 1  it shows 1 in balance box.. it need to show before another key is pressed is there any solution

Comment: is there any possibility using same code with loops...